# What does [a b] = max(.9) do in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

This doesn't make any sense to me and I'm not sure what to even search for.

Matlab code:

```
[a b] = max(.9);
```

Output:

```
a =
      0.9

b = 
      1
```

Why is it increasing by 1/10?  What does [a b] do when on the left side of equal sign?

Comment: Looking for the `max` function in the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) would be a good starter

Comment: Yes, that would have been a good place to start.  Coming from R and thought it only returned one thing.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`max`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) is used to find the maximum value of an array. The second output (if requested), [returns the index that corresponds to the first value in the array that is equal to the maximum value](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#outputarg_I).

```
[max_value, max_index] = max([1 3 3 2]);
%   max_value = 3
%   max_index = 2
```

In your case, you are passing a scalar (a `1 x 1` array) to `max`, therefore the scalar *is the maximum* and the maximum appears at index 1.

Answer (score 1):

> [M,I] = max(A) finds the indices of the maximum values of A and returns them in output vector I, using any of the input arguments in the previous syntaxes. If the maximum value occurs more than once, then max returns the index corresponding to the first occurrence.

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com